# Get a text item from an c# SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web and Razor, I create a select list:

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "1" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value =  "2" });

SelectList selectList = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", null);
```

Later, I want to get the text associated with a specific element in selectList. As a newbie, I'd think I could do this:

```
selectList.Items[1].Text
```

But that results in the message, "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'"

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try:

```
selectList.Skip(1).First().Text;
```

Or:

```
selectList.Where(p => p.Value == "2").First().Text;
```

Comment: Thanks Francisco. "selectList.Skip(1).First().Text;" worked perfectly. The "Where" clause would work in my original post, but in reality the "values" are numbered the same as the index[] (I only have the index number).

Comment: There is no need to use both *.Where(a => b)* and then *.First()*. Simply use *.First(a => b)* instead, which works exactly the same way.

Comment: The second: `Where(p => p.Value == item.Value)` is what I'm trying to use, but == throws an error for string comparisons in .cshtml pages.  I'm having the same issue with Skip as in a select list the value, text pairs are all text, whereas you are using int values. How to do this with text?

Comment: @PaulGibson the == should work with text. An alternative is to use the function string.Equals(text1,text2) for comparison of two texts.

Answer (score 5):

You could convert it to a `List` which would give you access to an indexer

```
selectList.Items.ToList()[1].Text
```

Comment: for me it doesn't compile; `selectList.Items` doesn't seem to have a `ToList`. Am I missing something?

Comment: ToList is a LINQ extension, you need to include the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: I had the `using`, but there must have been some problem in the intellisense yesterday. +1, It works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
selectList.Items.ElementAt(0);
```

need `using System.Linq` Namespace

Comment: This doesn't work. ElementAt() isn't a member of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
selectList.Items.FindByValue("1").Text
```