# MVC ViewBag Two Dimentional Array - How to access elements from controller

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a simple MVC C# controller with 2 dimention array.

```
ViewBag.states = new SelectList(db.states, "state_code", "state_zone");
```

If `state_code = "FL"`, I want to get its `state_zone` value in the controller

I tried:

```
int newZone = ViewBag.states["FL"].state_zone
```

but I get error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Any ideas?

Comment: You can access items from ViewBag like "ViewBag.states.Items[0]" based on array index only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ViewBag.states` is dynamic property, you can't use indexer of `SelectList` against it because `state_zone` already stored inside `Text` property:

```
int newZone = ViewBag.states["FL"].state_zone;
```

Also this declaration seems possible but may throwing indexing error as described in comment:

```
var zone = ViewBag.states as SelectList;

int newZone = Convert.ToInt32(zone.Items[0].Text); // error: 'cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
```

To use `SelectList` item indexer inside `ViewBag` object, you need to convert it into `SelectList` first, then use LINQ methods to reveal its value:

```
var zone = ViewBag.states as SelectList;

int newZone = Convert.ToInt32(zone.Skip(n).First().Text); // n = any index number

// alternative:
int newZone = Convert.ToInt32(zone.Where(p => p.Value == "[any_value]").First().Text);
```

Similar issue:

[Get a text item from an c# SelectList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862611/get-a-text-item-from-an-c-sharp-selectlist)